# Ionic app showing blank screen on opening

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have made an ionic app. I have successfully build the apk and installed the app on my phone. However when I opened the app, it showed a blank screen. So I decided to debug the app in chrome on my laptop. I am getting the errors as shown in the image. Does anyone has any idea about it?

ionic - 5.4.4
cordova - 6.4.0
gradle - 5.6.1

[image]

```
runtime-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cordova.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
vendor-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
polyfills-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
styles-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cordova_plugins.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/assets/icon/favicon.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: Please open your console and check is there any errors

Comment: I have already posted the errors. Please check.

Comment: Can you run `ionic cordova build android --prod` with no issues?

Comment: Yes, with no issues

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the base href in my index.html from / to ./

```
  <base href="./" />
```